# Reporting Tab is blank in SOAP UI Pro

Tags: soapui

I am trying to customize the Test Result Report using the Reporting Tab in the SOAP UI Pro. I found that the Reporting tab is totally blank for me and even after adding/creating 3-4 reports, it is not showing any details.

Comment: A screen shot would be helpful? And what the user actions to reproduce this? what is your software version? Please update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: SoapUI Reporting Tab]

This might be the solution. Let me know if it works